# TypeError: Calculating dot product in python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, typeerror, dot-product

I need to write a Python function that returns the sum of the pairwise products of `listA` and `listB` (the two lists will always have the same length and are two lists of integer numbers).

For example, if `listA = [1, 2, 3]` and `listB = [4, 5, 6]`, the dot product is `1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6`, so the function should return: `32`

This is how I wrote the code so far, but it produces an error.

```
def dotProduct(listA, listB):
    '''
    listA: a list of numbers
    listB: a list of numbers of the same length as listA
    '''
    sum( [listA[i][0]*listB[i] for i in range(len(listB))] )
```

It prints:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

How can I change this code so that the elements in the list can be multiplied element-wise?

Comment: remove `[0]`, A is a list, not list of list

Comment: If `listA` is a list of integers, then `listA[i]` is an integer. So how can you do `listA[i][0]`?

Comment: Try `sum(a*b for a,b in zip(listA, listB))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `[0]`, and it works:

`sum( [listA[i]*listB[i] for i in range(len(listB))] )`

More elegant and readable, do:

`sum(x*y for x,y in zip(listA,listB))`

Or even better:

```
import numpy
numpy.dot(listA, listB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the offending portion (attempting to subscript an int):

```
sum([listA[i]*listB[i] for i in range(len(listB))])
```